# Android offline app to visualize GeoTIFF maps (or any well-known raster format)

Tags: geotiff-tiff, software-recommendations, android, jpg

I like to go to mountain, and got lots of GeoTIFF maps, which I can convert to other formats with GlobalMapper (JPG+JGW, ECW, ...).

However, I haven't found an Android app to:
- show these raster images
- show my position, at the same time

I tested QGIS Mobile, but it did not show my position. Any other alternative?

Answer (score 3):

**Custom Maps** created by Marko Teittinen [This app currently has 99 Five Stars out of 138 reviews]

Use almost any map image as offline GPS map.

Custom Maps makes it easy to create GPS maps from map images, and those maps can be used anywhere, even when you have no data signal for your Android device (it works on both phones and tablets).

Custom Maps can use photos of paper maps or brochures, and pictures of maps posted at trailheads or at the entrances to amusement parks. **It can also use .jpeg or .png images downloaded from the internet and screenshots of PDF maps.**

> All you have to do is choose two (or more) matching points that are
>   common to both the map image and Google Maps, and Custom Maps can then
>   show your GPS location on the map.

As the map images are stored on the phone, Custom Maps works offline without data signal. This is useful if you go hiking in national or state parks, and it can help you avoid international roaming charges abroad.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.custommapsapp.android

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Custom Maps mentioned below, I would suggest GeoViewer.  It can do what you need.

It can load MrSID and JPEG2000 formats from local storage and arrange them automatically.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lizardtech.activity

Answer (score 2):

Try Orux maps. It allows downloading tiles for offline viewing and you can also use your own georeferenced images. It also has some other nice functionalities that might be useful to you. And it's free!

Answer (score 0):

My free app DogSheep can overlay a jpg or png image on top of an offline map in Mapsforge format. So far, rotation, scaling, and translation is supported. The screenshot in the Google Play store shows a 1917 map of Stanley Park overlayed on top of the modern map.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dogsheep

Answer (score 0):

The [Avenza Maps](https://www.avenza.com/avenza-maps/) app will do this on Android ([play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Avenza)) or IOS ([app store](https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id388424049)).

On android when I tried to open a GeoTIFF image, it showed up as one of the options to open it with, then it automatically imported it into the app's library and aligned it in its georeferencing system.

Great when I download a GeoTIFF topo from the USGS [topoView](https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/topoview/viewer/) and want to use them offline.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer to one you posted at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44383/displaying-georeferenced-images-on-android/458692#458692

Comment: Yes, it was a very similar question. I had both these open and was trying things when I stumbled upon a solution that worked for what I was trying to do with both these questions.