# Displaying Georeferenced Images on Android

Tags: geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, software-recommendations, overlay, android

I'm looking for an Android application (best would be Open Source), that can display georeferenced images on top of a map (Google, OSM, ...).

By Georeferenced I mean that the images four corners are related to world coordinates and a SRS like in GeoTiff or image + worldfile + prj-file. I DO NOT understand a photo + EXIF-Geotag.

A plus would be the possibility to georeference an image.

I would like to georeference in Android, because I sometimes have unreferenced Plans on my SD-card or find maps out there, take a photo of them, and overlay them with my base map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [MapsForge](http://mapsforge.org) - I have implemented an extension to the overlays that displays georeferenced images (sadly it was for a client and I can't release the code but it was pretty easy).

Answer (score 1):

I can't point to an app that currently does this, but you should see more apps supporting this type of feature soon due to the new Android Maps API V2 that came out a few weeks ago.

Android Maps V2 directly supports a "GroundOverlay", which is an image overlaid on the map:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay

Maps V2 API is compatible with all Android devices with Android 2.2 and greater.

With Android Maps V1 API, this functionality wasn't nearly as simple to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can georef your map on global mapper and export that as gmmp file
open this file in globalmapper android app, real time location and importing maps is free in this app, good luck

Answer (score 0):

The [Avenza Maps](https://www.avenza.com/avenza-maps/) app will do this on Android ([play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Avenza)) or IOS ([app store](https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id388424049)).

On Android when I tried to open a GeoTIFF image, it showed up as one of the options to open it with, then it automatically imported it into the app's library and aligned it in its georeferencing system.

Great when I download a GeoTIFF topo from the USGS [topoView](https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/topoview/viewer/) and want to use them offline.